Gross-Neveu model as effective theory for Yukawa model
I'm currently working on a comparison between the Yukawa model and the Gross-Neveu model, and I need some guidance on how to compute the Yukawa Lagrangian in the large mass $M$ limit. I am looking for an approach similar to Maggiore's in his QFT book, Chapter 8.1, but using functional methods. Specifically, I'm looking at the following Lagrangian:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{\text{Yukawa}} = \bar{\psi}\left(i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m_f\right) \psi + \frac{1}{2} \left(\partial_\mu \phi\right)^2 - \frac{1}{2} M_\phi^2 \phi^2 - g \bar{\psi} \phi \psi
\end{equation}
I am interested in understanding the behavior of this Lagrangian when the mass $M_\phi^2 \gg p^2$ of the scalar field $\phi$. In particular, I am considering using the partition function to obtain the effective Lagrangian in this limit:
\begin{equation}
Z=\int \mathcal{D} \bar{\psi} \mathcal{D} \psi \mathcal{D} \phi \, e^{i \int d^4 x \mathcal{L}_{\text{Yukawa}}}
\end{equation}
Then integrating out the scalar field $\phi$,
\begin{equation}
\int \mathcal{D} \phi \, e^{i \int d^4 x \left( \frac{1}{2} \phi \left(\square + M_\phi^2\right) \phi - g \bar{\psi} \phi \psi \right)}
\end{equation}
My question: How can I integrate out $\phi$ so that the final answer appears as $\frac{i}{p^2 - M_\phi^2} \approx \frac{i}{M_\phi^2}$, when $M_\phi^2 \gg p^2$?
Additionally, how can this procedure lead to the effective Lagrangian density of the Gross-Neveu model:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{GN}} = \bar{\psi}\left(i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m_f\right) \psi + \frac{g_{\mathrm{GN}}}{2} (\bar{\psi} \psi)^2
\end{equation}
Any insights, detailed explanations, or references to relevant literature would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

The quick way for "integrating out" a given field from a Lagrangian when typically talking about the path integral formalism can be done in the following manner. Given that the Yukawa lagrangian is
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_\text{Yukawa} & =\overline{\psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m_f\right)\psi + \frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2}M_\phi^2\phi^2 - g\overline{\psi}\phi\psi\\
& = \overline{\psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m_f\right)\psi -\frac{1}{2}\phi\left(\Box + M_\phi^2\right)\phi - g\overline{\psi}\phi\psi
\end{align}
where I integrated by parts on the kinetic term using $A\partial_\mu B = -B\partial_\mu A$ (assuming proper boundary conditions). The equations of motion with respect to $\phi$ are then
\begin{equation}
\phi = -g\frac{\overline{\psi}\psi}{\Box + M_\phi^2}.
\end{equation}
If we substitute this into our Lagrangian calling it $\mathcal{L}_{\text{Yukawa}}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}'$ then
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}' & = \overline{\psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m_f\right)\psi -\frac{1}{2}\left(-g\frac{\overline{\psi}\psi}{\Box + M_\phi^2}\right)\left(\Box + M_\phi^2\right)\left(-g\frac{\overline{\psi}\psi}{\Box + M_\phi^2}\right) - g\overline{\psi}\phi\psi\\
& = \overline{\psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m_f\right)\psi  - \frac{g^2}{2}(\overline{\psi}\psi)\left(\frac{1}{\Box + M_\phi^2}\right)(\overline{\psi}\psi) - g\overline{\psi}\left(-g\frac{\overline{\psi}\psi}{\Box + M_\phi^2}\right)\psi\\
& = \overline{\psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m_f\right)\psi - \frac{3g^2}{2}(\overline{\psi}\psi)\left(\frac{1}{\Box + M_\phi^2}\right)(\overline{\psi}\psi).
\end{align}
We can then write the denominator of the second terms as a series expansion in small $\Box/M_\phi^2\ll 1$ implying $M_\phi^{-2}(1 + \Box/M_\phi^2)^{-1}\simeq M_\phi^{-2}(1 - \Box/M_\phi^2 + \cdots)$ giving us our final Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}' = \overline{\psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m_f\right)\psi - \frac{3g^2}{2M_\phi^2}(\overline{\psi}\psi)^2 + \frac{3g^2}{2M_\phi^2}(\overline{\psi}\psi)\Box(\overline{\psi}\psi) + \cdots
\end{equation}
This is essentially Gross-Neveu model but I would change the sign on the Yukawa coupling to be $+g$ instead of $-$ then the final answer will not have a factor of $3/2$ but instead $1/2$ and will then be $+,-$ not $-,+$ (this is the traditional form then).
Let me know if you have any questions. There is a more rigorous way to derive the low energy effective action using Schwinger Proper time and the path integral, but this should suffice.
EDIT: The more rigorous way (which will give you the same answer...) involves using the definition of the effective action, which in this case since we are integrating out a scalar field is
\begin{equation}
\int \mathcal{D}\overline{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi \exp(i\Gamma[\psi,\overline{\psi}])\equiv \int \mathcal{D}\overline{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\phi \exp\left[i\int d^4x\left(\overline{\psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m_f\right)\psi + \frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2}M_\phi^2\phi^2 - g\overline{\psi}\phi\psi\right)\right]
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma[\psi,\overline{\psi}]$ is the effective action. You will then need the following Gaussian integral identity (from Wikipedia)
\begin{equation}
\int d^4x\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2}xMx + iJx\right) = \frac{\mathcal{N}}{\sqrt{\text{det}(M)}}\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2}JM^{-1}J\right)
\end{equation}
The operator $M$ in this case will just be $(\Box + M_\phi^2)$ with the current $J$ being $\overline{\psi}\psi$. I'll leave it up to you to determine the determinant of the scalar propagator (hint: page 374 of Peskin & Schroeder or chapter 33 of Schwartz's QFT text. Be careful when evaluating the determinant on your own though since the $0$-modes will make you think the whole thing vanishes but it doesn't). You can already see though that the effective action from the path integral is going to match the derivation above after expanding out the non-local $M$ in the same way we did prior. (I actually think the determinant of $M$ (for some reason) will be 1... don't quote me on that).

I understand your approach to solving it. Could you point me to resources or references where I can learn more about the "more rigorous way" using Schwinger Proper time and path integral methods? I appreciate it! I'm trying to include this as a review in my PhD dissertation. @MathZilla

@EverlinMartins I updated the question, please see the edits. If you want a proof of the Gaussian integral use, just Google something along the lines of "pfaffian, bosonic and fermionic integrals, Gaussian integral identity," etc. Or more more general, Berezin integrals.
